# Compilation errors in Verilog

Tags: mips, verilog

I am designing a 32 bit MIPS proccessor in verilog and i just finished the RegisterFile. when i try to compile i get these errors:

** Error: C:\Users\Montifas\Desktop\Organwsi\RegisterFile.v(14): 'i' is an invalid type in Generate loop. Must be a genvar.
** Error: C:\Users\Montifas\Desktop\Organwsi\RegisterFile.v(16): near "[": syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting IDENTIFIER or TYPE_IDENTIFIER
** Error: C:\Users\Montifas\Desktop\Organwsi\RegisterFile.v(23): near "[": syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting IDENTIFIER or TYPE_IDENTIFIER

i paste the code up to the point that these messages show with the lines as comments:

```
module RegFile (clock, reset, raA, raB, wa, wen, wd, rdA, rdB);
    input clock, reset, wen;
    input [4:0] raA, raB, wa;
    input [31:0] wd;
    output [31:0] rdA, rdB;
    reg [31:0] data[31:0]; 
    integer i;

    always @ (negedge clock or negedge reset);
        begin
            if(~reset)
                begin
                    for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1) //LINE14
                        begin
                            data[i] = 1'b0;  //LINE16
                        end
                end
            else if(reset)
                begin       
                    if(wen)
                        begin
                                data[wa] <= wd;  //LINE23
                        end
                end
        end
```

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon on the first line of the always block confused the compiler, making it think the remaining coded is an inferred generated block.

Other issue, your reset is using a blocking assignment to assign a 1-bit value to a 32-bit flop. Use non-blocking ans make the bit size 32-bits. Also the `else if(reset)` is not need. reset is a sinle bit value, just an `else` works.

```
always @ (negedge clock or negedge reset) // <-- no semicolon 
    begin
        if(~reset)
            begin
                for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1) //LINE14
                    begin
                        data[i] <= 32'b0;  //LINE16 // <-- non-blocking 32-bit
                    end
            end
        else // <-- 'if(reset)' is not needed
            begin       
                if(wen)
                    begin
                            data[wa] <= wd;  //LINE23
                    end
            end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you have a semicolon after your always statement, so the rest of the code in your always block is not actually in your always block.  The second problem is that i should be `genvar` not an integer when used like this.

```
module RegFile (clock, reset, raA, raB, wa, wen, wd, rdA, rdB);
    input clock, reset, wen;
    input [4:0] raA, raB, wa;
    input [31:0] wd;
    output [31:0] rdA, rdB;
    reg [31:0] data[31:0]; 
    genvar i;

    always @ (negedge clock or negedge reset)
        begin
            if(~reset)
                begin
                    for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1) //LINE14
                        begin
                            data[i] = 1'b0;  //LINE16
                        end
                end
            else if(reset)
                begin       
                    if(wen)
                        begin
                                data[wa] <= wd;  //LINE23
                        end
                end
        end
```

Comment: Close, but wrong. `i` should be an `integer`. `genvar` is for generate loops. The semicolon on the first line of the always block confused the compiler, making it think the remaining coded was an inferred generated block.